# Are ⟨ll⟩ and ⟨li⟩ distinct in lleísmo dialects?

Tags: pronunciación, fonología, yeísmo

Lleísmo dialects of Spanish are those that retain the distinction between /ʎ/ ⟨ll⟩ and /ʝ/ ⟨y⟩, in contrast to yeísmo dialects, which have merged the two phonemes. [Here are maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ye%C3%ADsmo#Geographic_extent) showing lleísmo areas in pink.

In lleísmo dialects, is /ʎ/ ⟨ll⟩ distinct from the sequence /lj/ ⟨li⟩ when followed by a vowel? The only minimal pair I can think of is **llana**/**liana**. Are there others?

(Note that I am referring to ⟨li⟩ only when followed by a vowel, so the ⟨i⟩ functions as a glide /j/, as in **familia**, not as in **listo**.)

This is similar to a discussion of the distinction between /ɲ/ ⟨ñ⟩ and the sequence /nj/ ⟨ni⟩ when followed by a vowel. I have read varying opinions as to whether these are distinct. Minimal pairs for these seem to be rare as well, such as **uñón**/**unión** and **taña**/**Tania**.

Comment: As far as I know, no Spanish speaker will fail to make the distinction between liana and llano.  Of course, how they pronounce ll as in Argentina. Uruguay etc.  where ll becomes /ʃ/ is what changes.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero está mal. El LLeísmo no consiste en mantener la distinción sino en pronunciar la ‘y’ y la ‘ll’ ambas como /ʎ/, que dicho sea de paso es algo muy raro.

Sí, son distintos fonemas, como bien decís en tu pregunta. Para que quede más claro [‘la liana llana no está’](https://forvo.com/word/la_liana_llana_no_est%C3%A1/#eshttps://forvo.com/word/la_liana_llana_no_est%C3%A1/#es). Un audio vale más que mil palabras.

Pero en mi opinión es distinto a lo de la eñe. La pronunciación /ʎ/ viene a ser algo así como la más ‘tradicional’ o ‘purista’ por lo que dudo que quienes la empleen piensen que es lo mismo que /lj/. No es una buena idea mezclarlos por más que hayan pocas palabras que se confundan, es motivo de bullying.

En cambio, lo otro es un fenómeno que se viene dando en la Argentina hasta donde sé, que consiste en pronunciar /ɲ/ como /nj/. Y aunque todavía se escucha alguno que otro llorando con que “la ‘eñe’ no es ‘ene-i’”, sinceramente no veo cómo podría arruinar la pronunciación. Como mínimo, este caso está más peleado.

En ambos casos *minimal pairs for these seem to be rare*. Pero la mayoría es capaz de tirarte algún bolazo por la /lj/; mientras en el otro caso, si el entorno lo permite, se pronuncia cómo salga.